# The "x-amz-security-token" Parameter is Missing from S3 Pre-Signed URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am generating presigned post url using this

```
 response = s3.generate_presigned_post(
        'uploads',
         'myurl/24a5c08c2e64/${filename}',
        Fields={
            'x-amz-meta-id': id,
        },
        Conditions=[
                ["starts-with", "$key", "myurl/"],
                {'x-amz-meta-id': id},
            ],
        ExpiresIn=(3*60*60),
    )
```

but I am unable to upload file because I am not getting **x-amz-security-token** in response . so what could be reason ? please help

that's how I am uploading using Postman and getting Access Denied error  [image]

Comment: "upload file" - how exactly are you uploading the file. Please describe all the commands and procedure in detail.

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting x-amz-security-token in response"?

Comment: I think this is because you used IAM User credentials to sign the URL. If you had used STS credentials, you would have `x-amz-security-token` in the returned URL. Either way, it's there in the URL if needed and absent if not needed. How is your upload attempt actually failing?

Comment: @jarmod on uploading I am getting  Access Denied error . when I upload without   `x-amz-security-token` as not getting in response

Comment: Ignore `x-amz-security-token`; it's a red herring. Use whatever URL the generate_presigned_post() method returns to you. It looks like you're using PUT, but you asked for a pre-signed POST URL. If that's not the issue, then you need to make sure that the credentials used to sign this URL actually have permission to upload to the S3 bucket/key that you're trying to upload to, and that your upload meets the conditions specified in the POST policy. Also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789520/how-do-i-put-object-to-amazon-s3-using-presigned-url) as it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, since I was using Lambda, the problem was the `x-amz-security-token` parameter. Leaving this explanation here in case anybody else stumbles upon this issue.

In Lambda, since you don't use access keys, but it rather assumes a role through its IAM execution role (STS). This means that for each execution it generates temporary credentials with short expiry and uses them to execute whatever it needs (in this case, pre-signing a URL).

When actually downloading/uploading from the client-side, you need to send 'X-Amz-Security-Token' in the body with the value you get when pre-signing. Unfortunately this is not clearly documented by AWS.

On the server-side, in NodeJS generating the sessionToken would be:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const credentials = s3.config.credentials;
const sessionToken = credentials.sessionToken;
```

On the server-side, in PHP generating the sessionToken would be:

```
$credentials = $s3client->getCredentials()->wait();
$sessionToken = $credentials->getSecurityToken();
```

And on the client-side when uploading/downloading the file, you would send this as Body:

```
"acl": presignUploadData.acl, // for upload
"key": presignUploadData.key, // the key you presigned for download/upload
"X-Amz-Credential": presignUploadData.XAmzCredential,
"X-Amz-Algorithm": presignUploadData.XAmzAlgorithm,
"X-Amz-Date": presignUploadData.XAmzDate,
"Policy": presignUploadData.Policy,
"X-Amz-Signature": presignUploadData.XAmzSignature,
"X-Amz-Security-Token": presignUploadData.XAmzSecurityToken, // this is the new part
```